# how to get this query in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database

I have this collection...

```
> db.banks.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54f37cbb44aec3b01b7db8f4"),
        "name" : "A",
        "branches" : [
                {
                        "branch_id" : 8561,
                        "name" : "X",                            
                },
                {
                        "branch_id" : 8576,
                        "name" : "Y",                            
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54f37cbb44aec3b01b7db8f5"),
        "name" : "B",
        "branches" : [
                {
                        "branch_id" : 3238,
                        "name" : "Z",                            
                }
        ]
}
```

with this command :

```
db.banks.aggregate({$project{"branches.name":1,"_id":0}});
```

get this result :

```
{ "branches" : { { "name" : "X" }, { "name" : "Y" } } }
{ "branches" : { { "name" : "Z" } } }
```

but; how I get this result?
(In fact, one object and without "branches".)

```
{{"name" : "X"}, {"name" : "Y"}, {"name" : "Z"}}
```

very thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could go about this is to do an `$unwind` first in the aggregation pipeline to get a deconstructed array with a document for each element and then group by the array element `$branches.name`:

```
db.banks.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$branches'},
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                name: '$branches.name'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            name: '$_id.name'
        }
    },
    { $sort : { "name" : 1 } }
])
```

Outputs:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "X"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Y"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Z"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```